# Modifying one row (in a loop) using data.table and .SD in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table, row, subset

I am new to data.table, but I need to speed up a dplyr code and so far I divided the processing time by 20, so needless to say I'd like to master that library. Understand by that introduction that processing time is the essence.

I have to modify rows using a loop because some columns are inter-connected. The use of a loop is not a matter addressed here: I will use a loop and there is no workaround, for other reasons not shown.
I already know what I'll use in my code to get the results needed because it's obviously the fastest, BUT I know there's a .SD way to do it, which would allow me a deeper understanding of that library, hence I seek your advices.

So, just to be clear: consider this post as an exercise that will help me understanding a subtlety in the use of .SD. I will present a simple table and a simple function (mean) but these are far from being the actual data (I use a self-made windowed mean). But if anyone can get the same results by using "mean" and .SD, then the problem is solved and I will learn something I don't know yet.
Sorry for the authoritative tone I use here, I just mean to be clear: I want to know what went wrong in my approach.

The very simplified table and goals are:

```
temp <- data.table(a=c(0,10), b=c(15,25))
#initialize 1rst row
temp[1, `:=`(worksA=a, worksB=b)]
#in the (not shown) loop, starting row 2, worksA & worksB update a mean with fresh data:
temp[2, `:=`(worksA=mean(temp$a[1:2]), worksB=mean(temp$b[1:2]))]
```

Thus you get what I want (but note that I will use a self-made "mean" function with a rolling window, so actually using cummean will not do):

```
    a  b worksA worksB
1:  0 15      0     15
2: 10 25      5     20
```

My 1rst failure was:

```
temp[2, `:=`(tryA=mean(a[1:2]),tryB=mean(b[1:2]))]
```

creates NA's. I guessed that I could not use row selection to create a column by reference, so I dealt with it using "$" (working solution); still I suspected .SD would do the trick, so trial "number" 2:

```
temp[2, c("tryA", "tryB"):=lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]
```

same. Funny fact, if you use na.rm:

```
temp[2, `:=`(tryA=mean(a[1:2], na.rm=TRUE),tryB=mean(b[1:2], na.rm=TRUE))]
```

or:

```
temp[2, c("tryA", "tryB"):=lapply(.SD[1:2], mean, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]
```

you get tryA & tryB row 2 updated with values a & b from the same row, as if it calculated the mean only with row 2 values.
Regarding to that matter, I try not to use the row selection on 1rst parameter (without "2" after 1rst braquet):

```
temp[, c("tryA", "tryB"):=lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]
```

which of course gives:

```
    a  b worksA worksB tryA tryB
1:  0 15      0     15    5   20
2: 10 25      5     20    5   20
```

i.e. the values I wanted printed on all rows. Better, but not what I want.

Microbenchmark tells me that my working solution is close to 20x faster than the lapply function anyway, so I give up on that.
But can anyone explain why my attempts (except for the last one, this one is crystal clear) were wrongly coded and how I could have edited 1 row at a time with a user-defined function and .SD ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example that depends on the inter-connectedness of the columns? Otherwise, a cumulative function should work, as pointed out by @sindri_baldur.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do, and with mention of `cummean` in sindri_baldur's answer and some of your code, I wonder if 2 rows is insufficient to demostrate what you're trying to do. Is this a cumulative operation or a rolling window? You said you have a "self-made mean function" which seems at odds with "time is of the essence", where UDFs are often the problem, not the solution.

Comment: Actually, a[2] is the result of a heavy computation calculated on another column, say c[1]. So I need 1rst row initialized, c[1] then computes, the 2nd row is updated with c[1], and so on. The "for" loop is not an issue, and "cummean" would be OK in that example, but I have a few self-made functions to use here (I do not use "mean", in fact !), so understanding why the "mean" function fails is the main point. I read a few things on .SD use but none of them were about modifying a single row.

Comment: As for the UDF, they are not the bottlenecks, this I could check by profiling the code. The self-made "mean" function is just a weighted mean (here you have a rolling window) discarding out-of-boundaries values according to a few criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK OK, what about a good old self-answer ?

Don't take it as a narcissistic move, since I understand now how my question was... dumb. It was all a misuse of the data.table language: I wanted to edit & select at the same time.

.SD is a subset of data, so `temp[2, lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]` could not give anything but NA's, because I asked R to return several rows of subset (`.SD[1:2]`) out of a single row data.table (`temp[2,`). That 1rst part (`[2,`) was considered by R for a selection, not an edition.

`temp[, lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]` gave the results I wanted, so that was the untouchable part I had to edit *into* the table, that edition request being written in an upper hierarchy of the code, where the "2" should be.

Thus `temp[2, c("worksA", "worksB"):=temp[, lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]]` does exactly what I meant: 1rst part (LHS) asks for a modification, 2nd part (RHS of `:=`) is what I want to insert.
.SD will return an output, not edit itself in the table it is extracted from. Sooo obvious, my bad.

As for benchmarks, $referencing turned out to be about 2.8x faster than .SD, as expected:

```
microbenchmark("$ref"={temp[2, `:=`(worksA=mean(temp$a[1:2]), worksB=mean(temp$b[1:2]))]}, ".SD"={temp[2, c("worksA", "worksB"):=temp[, lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]]}, times=10000L)
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
# $ref  390.601  427.2185  593.3664  479.921  558.4865  38580.97 10000  a 
#  .SD 1102.362 1224.5490 1681.0160 1373.182 1576.1190 269964.59 10000   b
```

Sorry for the fuss, problem solved, I know more now (pun !), let's go back to work.
Thanks a lot to you all !

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Reduce` with `accumulate=T` option to generate cumulative lists of each column:

```
library(data.table)

temp <- data.table(a=c(0,10), b=c(15,25))

temp[,lapply(.SD, function(x) Reduce(x,f=function(x,y) c(x,y),accumulate=T))]
#        a      b
#   <list> <list>
#1:      0     15
#2:   0,10  15,25
```

So that you can apply to them any summary function (mean in this example) with `sapply`:

```r
temp[,paste0('works',colnames(temp)):=lapply(.SD, function(x) sapply(Reduce(x,f=function(x,y) c(x,y),accumulate=T),function(x) mean(unlist(x))))][]
#>        a     b worksa worksb
#>    <num> <num>  <num>  <num>
#> 1:     0    15      0     15
#> 2:    10    25      5     20
```

Or with a recursive mean:

```
recursive.mean <- function(x) tail(stats::filter(x/2,1/2),1)
temp[,paste0('works',colnames(temp)):=lapply(.SD, function(x) sapply(Reduce(x,f=function(x,y) c(x,y),accumulate=T),function(x) recursive.mean(unlist(x))))][]

#       a     b worksa worksb
#   <num> <num>  <num>  <num>
#1:     0    15    0.0   3.75
#2:    10    25    2.5   6.25
```

Comment: Alright, this approach does what I'm looking for, with all constraints respected (I can use a user-defined function), plus the processing time that is way below my expectations (1641 microsec vs. 1100 when using $ referencing). Might not go as smoothly with a few thousands rows (lists), though... Anyway, should I understand there that even though `temp[, lapply(.SD[1:2], mean), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]` prints the results I want (1 row !), .SD approaches does not fit for EDITING 1 row ? Because out of the 2 solutions suggested (here+cummean), it was always about editing ALL rows. Thanks again !